# .Net SqlClient BULK INSERT hanging

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, bulk-load

We are using .Net SqlClient to bulk insert data from a remote server to our SQL Server.

Somedays our ETL fails so we are trying to figure out the reason for that.

What we can notice is that a bulk insert, let's call it BI1 is hanging for too long compared to other bulk inserts started at the same time.

By monitoring the running queries on our SQL server we can see that this BI1 query is changing status, sometimes "`suspended`", sometimes "`runnable`". I have not seen "running" at the moment, but maybe it is very fast when it is running and I don't see it between my refresh queries.
When it is "`suspended`" (most of the time), the wait type is "`ASYNC_NETWORK_IO`". The row count is always the same : 38.

My understanding is that the bulk insert is waiting to be fed with data to insert. Am I right?

The question here is how do I identify the underlying issue?

I already ruled out the network issue as there are other processes between these 2 machines at the same time which are completing successfully.
The destination table is pretty big (7M+ rows), but inserting seems to work fine and fast.

Comment: debug your .NET application that is feeding data. I would also suggest that you use SSIS for data transfers.

Comment: I am having EXACTLY the same issue (just on a much larger table and trying to insert 7M+ rows at a time). I get random failures with the system hanging on the same wait type. And other times it just works. Did you have any luck getting to the bottom of this??